# UI Sortable plugin for angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-sortable

Is there any plugin for angular 2, which can perform ui sorting similar to angular-ui/ui-sortable (angular 1 plugin) (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this might have what you need: https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd

Sortable demo halfway down this page: http://akserg.github.io/ng2-webpack-demo/#/dnd